# Meaning of "would" here

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

> After that incident, we never talked about our families again, but we did talk about our dolls. I **would** boast about how many animals mine had. “A cow, a pig, a really huge chicken!”
>
> And Tania **would** say, with a dismissive smile, “Mine live in a city. There is no space for farm animals. Their names are Sigrid, Amaranta, and Arabella. Amaranta and Arabella are scientists, but Sigrid is an actress.”

Is the word **would** here in this passage implying **every now and then**  ? Tania would say = Tania continually said every time in my house...

Answer (score 1):

"would" here is used to describe repeated actions or routines in the past, just like "used to "
 e.g. We **would** eat out on Sundays. (meaning: We **used to** eat out on Sundays.)
           e.g. And Tania **would** say.....(meaning: And Tania **used to** say.... .)

Comment: I'm not sure that the implication is clear that Tania's statement would necessarily be repeated or routine in this context. The writer is talking about how things changed following an incident, and to illustrate the discussion of dolls, gives Tania as an example. It may be that Tania only made the given statement once, but that the statement is illustrative of the discussion about dolls, which is itself an activity that was repeated.

Comment: Using "would" clearly implies that the statement was stated more than once.